# How to set the mode from a vimscript?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, mode

If I save the result of `:call mode()` in a variable, how can I restore that mode later?

Comment: I doubt there is an API in particular for the exotic modes like operator pending. Maybe could give us more insight about what you try to achieve and get a more appropriate suggestion?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I want to destroy a buffer, then create a new buffer exactly the same as it, in the same state

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an arbitrary mode programmatically, or at least not with a dedicated function like `:call setmode('n')`, which doesn't exist.

What you can do, however, is…

- start insert mode with `:help :startinsert`,
- start replace mode with `:help :startreplace`,
- like the two methods above, but switch to another mode from insert or replace mode,
- execute a normal mode command with `:help :normal`, which should leave you in normal mode,
- same as above but execute a normal mode command that switches to another mode, like `v` for visual mode,
- and other similar kinds of tricks…

See `:help mode-switching`.